# Python count element occurrence of list1 in list2

Tags: python, list, counting

In the following code, I want to count the occurrence of every word in `word_list` in `test`, the code below can do this job but it may not be efficient, is there any better way to do it?

```
word_list = ["hello", "wonderful", "good", "flawless", "perfect"]
test = ["abc", "hello", "vbf", "good", "dfdfdf", "good", "good"]

result = [0] * len(word_list)
for i in range(len(word_list)):
    for w in test:
        if w == word_list[i]:
            result[i] += 1

print(result)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count all the words in `test` in one go, then just get that count from the `Counter` for each word in `word_list`.

```
>>> word_list = ["hello", "wonderful", "good", "flawless", "perfect"]
>>> test = ["abc", "hello", "vbf", "good", "dfdfdf", "good", "good"]
>>> counts = collections.Counter(test)
>>> [counts[w] for w in word_list]
[1, 0, 3, 0, 0]
```

Or using a dictionary comprehention:

```
>>> {w: counts[w] for w in word_list}
{'perfect': 0, 'flawless': 0, 'good': 3, 'wonderful': 0, 'hello': 1}
```

Creating the counter should be O(n), and each lookup O(1), giving you O(n+m) for n words in `test` and m words in `word_list`.

Comment: wouldn't it be more efficient to do the filtering first?
Also, referring to that page: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity, the lookup in a list is O(n), this can be improved to O(1) if you convert `word_list` to a set.

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi What's with all that "do the lookup in a set" today? You're the second one to suggest that. Is my answer that unclear? I'm _never_ doing lookup in a list, only in a dict here, which is just as fast as lookup in a set. Also, what filtering?

Comment: Yes you are right I got confused with what I had in mind.
If you do:
    `words = set(word_list);
    new_test = [word for word in test if word in words];
    counts = collections.Counter(new_test)`
you might have faster results depending on the situation.

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi I don't think that that would be any faster. `Counter` does just one loop over the collection; your code does two: one for filtering, then one for creating the dictionary.

Comment: Well, that second loop might be way faster since I removed some terms in the list. Then again, it depends on the situation.

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi Even if the second loop is faster, the first one is not. Lets say `test` has n words and `word_list` has m, and s words are in both lists. My code has n+m steps (n for creating the counter, m for getting the values. Your variant has m+n+s+m (create set, filter, create counter, get values).

Comment: Ok, I get your point. However, I wasn't taking into account the set creation and getting the values. But I guess if you do precisely this then your answer is better in any situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in linear time using a dictionary.

```
word_list = ["hello", "wonderful", "good", "flawless", "perfect"]
test = ["abc", "hello", "vbf", "good", "dfdfdf", "good", "good"]

result = []
word_map = {}
for w in test:
    if w in word_map:
        word_map[w] += 1
    else:
        word_map[w] = 1

for w in word_list:
    result.append(word_map.get(w, 0))

print(result)
```

Comment: Nice "no libraries" solution, but even then you can make that code a bit more compact using `get` with default, e.g. `result.append(word_map.get(w, 0))`

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) and  [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

cnts = Counter(test)
word_cnts = dict(zip(word_list, itemgetter(*word_list)(cnts)))
```

Which gives:

```
>>> word_cnts
{'flawless': 0, 'good': 3, 'hello': 1, 'perfect': 0, 'wonderful': 0}
```

or if you rather want it as a `list`:

```
>>> list(zip(word_list, itemgetter(*word_list)(cnts)))
[('hello', 1), ('wonderful', 0), ('good', 3), ('flawless', 0), ('perfect', 0)]
```

Comment: Impressive display of functional programming, but I'd still prefer a list or dict comprehension. ;-)

Comment: @tobias_k The comprehensions were already "taken" by another answer. Otherwise I would have added them as well :-P

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use dictionnaries :

```
word_list = ["hello", "wonderful", "good", "flawless", "perfect"]
test = ["abc", "hello", "vbf", "good", "dfdfdf", "good", "good"]

result = {}
for word in word_list:
    result[word]=0
for w in test:
    if result.has_key(w):
        result[w] += 1
print(result)
```

But you would end with a different structure.
If you do not want that, you could try this instead

```
word_list = ["hello", "wonderful", "good", "flawless", "perfect"]
test = ["abc", "hello", "vbf", "good", "dfdfdf", "good", "good"]

result = {}
for w in test:
    if(result.has_key(w)):
        result[w] += 1
    else:
        result[w] = 1
count = [0] * len(word_list)
for i in range(len(word_list)):
    if (result.has_key(word_list[i])):
        count[i]=result[word_list[i]]
print(count)
```